# Segmentation Fault; Beginner

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I don't understand where I'm getting an error. I believe it's at the end part where the user inputs one of the choices from the menu.

```
int main()
{
    int i,j; /* counter variables */
    int size; /* array size */
    double data[size]; /* array variable */
    int o; /* response variable */
    printf("\nHow many numbers do you have in your data set?\n"); /* initial instructions */
    scanf("%d",&size); /* */
    printf("\nPlease enter those numbers.\n"); /* data set */
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){ /* loop to correspond a data point to an element */
        scanf("%lf",&data[i]); /* */
}

/* menu system */
printf("\nNow, please select the following operations:"); /* intro */
printf(" . . . "); /* the menu choices */
....
```

This right here is where I believe my problem is. But I don't know why it's coming up as an error. Is the syntax right?

```
scanf("%d",&o); /* */
if(o==1){  /* Displaying the data set*/
    for(j=0;j<size;j++){ /* loop to display each element of the array*/
        printf("\n%g,",data[j]); /* displaying the array */
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does this compile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int size; /* array size */
double data[size]; /* array variable */
```

This is the problem - `size` is uninitialized, the size of the `data` array is random.

You should read the `size` from the user first, then dynamically create the array, using `malloc`. Something like:

```
scanf("%d",&size);
//...
double* data = (double*)malloc( size * sizeof( double ) );
// NOTE: don't forget the `free` this memory later
```

Comment: He doesn't **need** malloc, especially given that he's not using the array outside the function. A variable-length array is just fine.

Comment: I will use the array elements outside the function. Does that mean I do have to use malloc

Comment: @H2CO3 - I agree, I didn't say it's a must.

Comment: @leovic - I think it depends on the type of usage. If you want to `return` it, for example, you'll need `malloc` for sure, because otherwise the memory will be automatically freed at the end of the function, defined the array.

Comment: By the way, thanks for the feedback. C is really interesting to learn but I'm just really bad at doing this solo.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign to array a maximum size:

```
#define MAX 100     // Immediately after #include ...

double data[SIZE];
```

Then create new variable to be initialized by user:

```
int newSize = 0;
scanf("%d", &newSize);
```

Now the new size of your array is `newSize` variable value